I can't cite references in my thesis
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 24.3) The top-level auxiliary file: abcd.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file abcd.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file abcd.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file abcd.aux (There were 3 error messages)
bibtex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for updates as a MiKTeX user.
Process exited with error(s)
Please correct it in texmaker

Welcome to TeX.se. It's impossible for us to help you with the information you've given.  Can you get a simple document to do a bibliography properly?  If not, show us that document, and we can probably tell you what's going on.

do you have any \cite commands in your document? The error message is suggesting that you do not.

Also, your document would appear to be lacking a \bibliographystyle directive.
